# If a linear form verify $\varphi (AB) = \varphi (BA)$ for all matrices $A,B$, then $\exists \lambda, \varphi = \lambda tr$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to show that if $\varphi : \mathcal{M}_n(K) \rightarrow K$ is a linear form such as $\forall(A,B)\in \mathcal{M}_n(K)^2, \varphi (AB) = \varphi(BA)$ then $\exists \lambda \in K, \varphi = \lambda tr$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* Consider $\varphi(E_{ik}E_{kj})=\varphi(E_{kj}E_{ik})$ for $i\ne j$ and also $\varphi(P^TE_{ii}P)=\varphi(E_{ii})$ for every permutation matrix $P$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the kernel of the $K$-linear map $\varphi:\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)\to K$ contains $\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$.  Thus, $\varphi$ factors through $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)\to\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)/\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$, or we may state that $\varphi$ factors through the trace map $\text{tr}:\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)\to K$.  Since every $K$-linear map from $K \to K$ is a multiplication by some scalar $\lambda\in K$, we conclude that $\varphi=\lambda\,\text{tr}$ for some $\lambda\in K$.